# How to get correct height and offset values of an element when using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get the offset and height of list items. Once I have those, I call a function on a parent directive.  *In the end, this will be transition elements in and out when they come into view.*

**Problem:**  Because of the `ng-repeat`(I don't know why), `el[0].offsetheight` and `el[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;` values are pretty much random; unless, I wrap a `$timeout` around the logic. *I think this is because the styles have time to render?*

**Question:**  how can I get an accurate offset and height w/o wrapping a `$timeout` or using a `$watch`.

**HTML:**

```
<dt  spyed ng-repeat="exp in experiences">
 ...
</dt>
```

**JS:**

```
app.directive('spyed', function () {
    return {
        require: '^scrollSpyer',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            // this value is mostly random after the $first ng-repeat item
            var offset = el[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
            // this value is also mostly randome after the $first ng-repeat item
            var theHeight = el[0].offsetHeight;
            // this fires the expMapper on parent directive.
            ctrl.expMapper(offset, theHeight);
        }
    };
});
```

*Sidenote on why not use a watcher:*
The reason I dont want to use a watcher is I'm pushing these values to collection in the parent directive.  I don't want to keep resetting the array which i'll have to do if it keeps firing `ctrl.expMapper()` on every 2way binding.

Parent Directive:

```
app.directive('scrollSpyer', function ($window, Experiences) {
    return {
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.experiences = [];
            this.expMapper = function(offset, height) {
                $scope.experiences.push({'offset': offset, 'height': height, 'inView': false});
            };
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            var i = 0;
            angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function() {

                if(i < scope.experiences.length) {
                    if (this.pageYOffset >= scope.experiences[i].offset) {
                        Experiences.status.push(scope.experiences[i]);
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        console.log('middle');
                    }
                }

                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: As far as my researches go $timeout with 0 seconds is required to start any calculation of dom element dimensions after the scope and the DOM have been refreshed.

Comment: I can suggest you to move the logic that will call the ctrl.expMapper into the ng-repeat item so it will be:  
'dt -> wrapper (spyed directive here) -> item-content.'

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4089at1L/). I tried to create this but all looks fine to me. The values do not seem random at all. Let me know if I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function in $scope:

```
$scope.getOffsets = function () {
    //Do your logic here
};
```

Note this small difference:

```
<dt  spyed ng-repeat="exp in experiences" ng-init="$last ? getOffsets(): ''">
    ...
</dt>
```

ng-init based on condition to check last index will make that happen without timeout